# Rough stroke in js canvas arcs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I was trying to draw a arc on canvas. But for some reason it is not smooth. Note that I added some css in the code too and also the responsive meta tag. Please check the snippet.

> This code is giving me a arc with rough strokes

[image: rough arc]

Any solution to make it smooth?

Added a snippet now. Note that the arc is drawn in draw function and I am using offscreen canvas to blit the result back to reduce draw calls.

```js
window.onload = main;
let canvas;
let frame;

class Widget {
  canvas;
  parent;
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  }
}

class Frame extends Widget{
  constructor(parent) {
    super();
    this.canvas.style.display = "block";
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.parent.appendChild(this.canvas);

    this.buffer = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.buffer.height = this.canvas.height;
    this.buffer.width = this.canvas.width;
  }

  blit() {
    let context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(this.buffer, 0, 0);
  }
}


function main() {
  frame = new Frame(document.body);
  animation();
}

function animation() {
  draw(frame.buffer);
  frame.blit();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}

function draw(canvas) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, alright I found the problem and the solution.
I needed to add beginPath() before my arc() function call.

```
function draw(canvas) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // beginPath() is important!!!
  ctx.beginPath()
  //
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

before adding beginPath() :

[image: before]

after adding beginPath():

[image: after]

Comment: As an added bonus - you are not taking the devicePixelRatio of the device screen into consideration. It's a rather simple fix, you can read more on it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#correcting_resolution_in_a_%3Ccanvas%3E

Comment: @GeorgiB.Nikolov Thanks for the suggestion.